# Using ISNULL to handle optional parameter hurts performance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms, isnull, sqlperformance

SQL Server 2008 R2

Note, I understand that performance issues can get complicated. My question is more general and pertains to behavior of `ISNULL` construct in general.

I have a SQL query that needs to optionally filter by given parameter, I accomplished that by appending following clause to the query:

```
WHERE tbl.Col1 = ISNULL(@col1, tbl.Col1)
```

What I see is that my query executes fine from within SSMS, but when fed to dapper it times out.

If I replace filter with following, behaviorally equivalent expression:

```
WHERE @col1 IS NULL OR tbl.Col1 = @col1
```

the query executes without timeout.

**Question:** why? Is there a known issue with `ISNULL` when used in this scenario that slows down query execution?

(I have not tried profiling the query yet, but will do that next)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: this question it's about `ISNULL(@col1, tbl.Col1)` and not about `ISNULL(tbl.Col1, @col1)`

```
WHERE tbl.Col1 = ISNULL(@col1, tbl.Col1)
```

1) You may add `RECOMPILE` query hint. In this case, SQL Server will [re]compile this query  at every execution. This means that will reevaluate following predicate `tbl.Col1 = ISNULL(@col1, tbl.Col1)` at every execution and

- if `@col` contains `NULL` then it will remove the condition is the column is mandatory (`NOT NULL`; because `WHERE tbl.Col1 = ISNULL(@col1, tbl.Col1)` => `WHERE tbl.Col1 = tbl.Col1`), else
- if `@col` contains something (is not null) then `WHERE tbl.Col1 = ISNULL(@col1, tbl.Col1)` is translated to `WHERE tbl.Col1 = @col1`

Example ([Adventure Works for SQL Server 2012](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/downloads/get/165399)):

[image]

Note: if `@col1` and `tbl.Col1` have different data types then SQL Server will convert `tbl.Col1` values to the data type of `@col1`. This implicit conversion *could* block a `Seek` on `tbl.Col1` (when `@col1` is not null).

2) `WHERE @col1 IS NULL OR tbl.Col1 = @col1` are [SARG-able predicates](http://sqlmag.com/database-performance-tuning/more-small-code-changes-bigger-sql-server-performance-improvements) and this means that SQL Server can filter rows using a `Seek` (if there is a index on `tbl.Col1`).

See also [Conor vs. more SARGable predicates](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/conor_cunningham_msft/archive/2010/12/18/conor-vs-more-sargable-predicates.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Functions in the WHERE clause prevent SQL from using indexes on the field.  So if Col1 has a nonclustered index on Col1, it can be used in your second example, but not the first.  This will cause the function to evaluate for each row (a clustered index scan), a potentially major performance hit.

See articles for details and examples:

[Database Journal](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3845381/T-SQL-Best-Practices-150-Don146t-Use-Scalar-Value-Functions-in-Column-List-or-WHERE-Clauses.htm)

[MSSQLTips](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1236/avoid-sql-server-functions-in-the-where-clause-for-performance/)